# Tailwind CSS Navbar controlled by scroll with animation

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-transitions, navbar, react-typescript

I made a function that controls Navbar. It hides when user scroll down and it shows when user scrolls up but i can't figure out how to add animation to this with Tailwind CSS ?
That's my first project with Tailwind and everywhere else I and regular `"transition-all duration..."` it works but here it doesn't apply it to that scroll "handler".

My code :

```
    const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
      const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
      const [prevScrollPosition, setPrevScrollPosition] = useState(0)
      const [visable, setVisable] = useState(true)
      const handleScroll = () => {
        const currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY
    
        if (currentScrollPosition > prevScrollPosition) {
          setVisable(false)
        } else {
          setVisable(true)
        }
        setPrevScrollPosition(currentScrollPosition)
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
      })
    
      return (
        <>
          <nav
            className={`transition ease-linear duration-700 border-gray-900 bg-gray-50 flex border-b w-full fixed z-50 ${
              visable
                ? "transition ease-linear duration-700"
                : "hidden transition ease-linear duration-700"
            }`}
          >
            <div className="flex-1 flex justify-center mr-auto py-3 px-10">
              <button
                onClick={() => setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)}
                type="button"
                className="flex-1 space-y-1.5 "
              >
                <Bars4Icon className="h-10 w-10 transition-all hover:scale-125 duration-300 hover:text-indigo-800" />
              </button>
              {isOpen && (
                <div className="w-full h-screen top-0 z-30 bg-black bg-opacity-60 absolute">
                  <div className="  text-indigo-900 h-screen bg-gray-50 absolute z-40 w-2/6 py-3 px-10 top-0 left-0">
                    <XMarkIcon
                      onClick={() => setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)}
                      className="h-12 w-12 mb-10 cursor-pointer hover:scale-125 transition-all duration-300"
                    />
                    <ul className="flex flex-col mb-10 gap-10 text-4xl font-thin">
                      <li
                        onClick={(e) => (window.location.href = "/")}
                        className=" cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 hover:pl-10  transition-all duration-300"
                      >
                        Home
                      </li>
                      <li
                        onClick={(e) => (window.location.href = "/offer")}
                        className=" cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 hover:pl-10 duration-300"
                      >
                        Offer
                      </li>
                      <li className=" hover:scale-110 hover:pl-10 duration-300">
                        Contact
                      </li>
                      <li className=" hover:scale-110 hover:pl-10 duration-300">
                        Team
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
              <div className="mx-36 invisible lg:visible transition-all hover:scale-110 duration-500">
                <button onClick={(e) => (window.location.href = "/")}>
                  <img src={logo} className="h-9" alt="Logo" />
                </button>
              </div>
              <span
                onClick={(e) => (window.location.href = "/offer")}
                className="flex flex-1 cursor-pointer transition-all duration-500 transform hover:text-indigo-800 justify-end ml-auto  decoration-indigo-800 hover:text-2xl underline-offset-8 underline  text-xl font-light whitespace-nowrap"
              >
                How it works ?
              </span>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default Navbar
```

I'm trying to do it step by step how Tailwind CSS documentation says with navbar behavior and also hamburger button that is handle with useState to open and close it and I can't figure out why these transitions don't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions will not play when changing the `display` value from or to `none`, as is the case here with `hidden`. You could consider transitioning between `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 100` via the `opacity-0` and `opacity-100` classes respectively to make a fade transition. You don't strictly need the `opacity-100` class since it is the default:

```
<nav
  className={`transition ease-linear duration-700 border-gray-900 bg-gray-50 flex border-b w-full fixed z-50 ${
    visable ? '' : 'opacity-0'
  }`}
>
```

The navigation will still be interactable, so we may want to apply `visibility: hidden` to it via the `invisible` class so it or any descendents are not interactable:

```
<nav
  className={`transition ease-linear duration-700 border-gray-900 bg-gray-50 flex border-b w-full fixed z-50 ${
    visable ? '' : 'opacity-0 invisible'
  }`}
>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! That explains a lot :)